# How to output exact character string "<?php"

Tags: php, html-parsing

I'm new to php, I have not been able to figure out how to output the exact string "`<?php`" as either an HTML string, outputing from a file (i.e. `file_get_contents(blah);`), or with `echo "<?php";` inside a code segment.  I assume it is getting interpreted as the opening of a php code segment because no data is output.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Should work fine:

```
<?php

print "<?php";
```

Answer (score 3):

More likely it's interpreted as an HTML tag, use

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");
```

Or replace the `<` with `&lt;`.

Comment: I new it had to be something simple. . .Thanks much - this did the trick!

Comment: @new2php: If it helped you, consider accepting this answer by clicking the large green tick mark under this question's score.